# Staying in another folder, how can i tar specific files from another directory?

Tags: linux, command, compression, redhat, tar

Thanks for your support,

I have the following folder structure on my linux laptop

```
/home
     /A
     /B
```

In folder "B", I have files of type *.csv, *.dat.

Now from folder A, How can I create a tar file containing files *.csv in folder B. I am running the command in folder A

Here is the command, I have tried but its not working,

In /home/A folder, I am running the following command

```
tar -cf /home/A/Sample1.tar -C /home/B/ZSBSDP4 *.csv
```

and also tried with this,

```
tar -cf /home/A/Sample1.tar -C /home/B/ZSBSDP4 --wildcards *.csv
```

For both of the commands, I get the following error,

```
tar: *.csv: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

In the tar file, I dont want to include the whole folder structure and this is the reason, I am using option -C (capital)

Moreover, the following command works but it tars all *.csv and *.dat files.

```
tar -cf /home/A/Sample1.tar -C /home/B/ZSBSDP4 .
```

Comment: This question belongs in http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the names in the tar command to remove the path.  (Assuming that you have GNU tar.)

```
tar -cf /home/A/Sample1.tar --transform 's,.*/\([^/]*\),\1,' /home/B/ZSBSDP4/*.csv
```

Note that if you specify more source directories on the command, you could accidentally put more than one file with the same name in the tar file.  Then when unpacking, the last one will overwrite those with the same name that precede it.

Comment: I dont want the path in the tar file. I just need .csv files to be tarred

Comment: Sorry for that. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the --exclude=PATTERN option:

```
tar -cf /home/A/Sample1.tar -C /home/B/ZSBSDP4 . --exclude=*.dat
```

Other "local file selection" options listed in the man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar